# Need to adjust in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I want to display the following figures simultaneously that is not above or lower. 
Also need to reduce the size. Please help me.

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
%\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw [color=black, fill=gray!50] (8*0.375,8*0.25) -- (8*0.6666,4*0.33333) -- (8*0.33333,8*0.33333) -- (1,4) -- cycle;
\draw 
( 4.50000000000000 , 1.30900000000000 )-- ( 4.49500000000000 , 1.34650000000000 )-- ( 4.49000000000000 , 1.30600000000000 )-- ( 4.48500000000000 , 1.35450000000000 )-- ( 4.48000000000000 , 1.33050000000000 )-- ( 4.47500000000000 , 1.33400000000000 )-- ( 4.47000000000000 , 1.30950000000000 )-- ( 4.46500000000000 , 1.31950000000000 )-- ( 4.46000000000000 , 1.34900000000000 )-- ( 4.45500000000000 , 1.34600000000000 )-- ( 4.45000000000000 , 1.37250000000000 )-- ( 4.44500000000000 , 1.44600000000000 )-- ( 4.44000000000000 , 1.36500000000000 )-- ( 4.43500000000000 , 1.39750000000000 )-- ( 4.43000000000000 , 1.35600000000000 )-- ( 4.42500000000000 , 1.38950000000000 )-- ( 4.42000000000000 , 1.43700000000000 )-- ( 4.41500000000000 , 1.43600000000000 )-- ( 4.41000000000000 , 1.39100000000000 )-- ( 4.40500000000000 , 1.40400000000000 )-- ( 4.40000000000000 , 1.38550000000000 )-- ( 4.39500000000000 , 1.43450000000000 )-- ( 4.39000000000000 , 1.45250000000000 )-- ( 4.38500000000000 , 1.37100000000000 )-- ( 4.38000000000000 , 1.43150000000000 )-- ( 4.37500000000000 , 1.42500000000000 )-- ( 4.37000000000000 , 1.40900000000000 )-- ( 4.36500000000000 , 1.38450000000000 )-- ( 4.36000000000000 , 1.40250000000000 )-- ( 4.35500000000000 , 1.37450000000000 )-- ( 4.35000000000000 , 1.38400000000000 )-- ( 4.34500000000000 , 1.42250000000000 )-- ( 4.34000000000000 , 1.41350000000000 )-- ( 4.33500000000000 , 1.40600000000000 )-- ( 4.33000000000000 , 1.41200000000000 )-- ( 4.32500000000000 , 1.40300000000000 )-- ( 4.32000000000000 , 1.39450000000000 )-- ( 4.31500000000000 , 1.38450000000000 )-- ( 4.31000000000000 , 1.42600000000000 )-- ( 4.30500000000000 , 1.43350000000000 )-- ( 4.30000000000000 , 1.40450000000000 )-- ( 4.29500500000000 , 1.42550000000000 )-- ( 4.29000500000000 , 1.46250000000000 )-- ( 4.28500500000000 , 1.38850000000000 )-- ( 4.28000500000000 , 1.45400000000000 )-- ( 4.27500500000000 , 1.69450000000000 )-- ( 4.27000500000000 , 1.65300000000000 )-- ( 4.26500500000000 , 1.67200000000000 )-- ( 4.26000500000000 , 1.68850000000000 )-- ( 4.25500500000000 , 1.64200000000000 )-- ( 4.25000500000000 , 1.64650000000000 )-- ( 4.24500500000000 , 1.66300000000000 )-- ( 4.24000500000000 , 1.66100000000000 )-- ( 4.23500500000000 , 1.64850000000000 )-- ( 4.23000500000000 , 1.66350000000000 )-- ( 4.22500500000000 , 1.67950000000000 )-- ( 4.22000500000000 , 1.63100000000000 )-- ( 4.21500500000000 , 1.65650000000000 )-- ( 4.21000500000000 , 1.70250000000000 )-- ( 4.20500500000000 , 1.64300000000000 )-- ( 4.20000500000000 , 1.67700000000000 )-- ( 4.19500500000000 , 1.66050000000000 )-- ( 4.19000500000000 , 1.63650000000000 )-- ( 4.18500500000000 , 1.65650000000000 )-- ( 4.18000500000000 , 1.60400000000000 )-- ( 4.17500500000000 , 1.66300000000000 )-- ( 4.17000500000000 , 1.62750000000000 )-- ( 4.16500500000000 , 1.68550000000000 )-- ( 4.16000500000000 , 1.69100000000000 )-- ( 4.15500500000000 , 1.64150000000000 )-- ( 4.15000500000000 , 1.62100000000000 )-- ( 4.14500500000000 , 1.64500000000000 )-- ( 4.14000500000000 , 1.65300000000000 )-- ( 4.13500500000000 , 1.67150000000000 )-- ( 4.13000500000000 , 1.65000000000000 )-- ( 4.12500500000000 , 1.67650000000000 )-- ( 4.12000500000000 , 1.67600000000000 )-- ( 4.11500500000000 , 1.70050000000000 )-- ( 4.11000500000000 , 1.67100000000000 )-- ( 4.10500500000000 , 1.67750000000000 )-- ( 4.10000500000000 , 1.67250000000000 )-- ( 4.09500500000000 , 1.65800000000000 )-- ( 4.09000500000000 , 1.67450000000000 )-- ( 4.08500500000000 , 1.69700000000000 )-- ( 4.08000500000000 , 1.63050000000000 )-- ( 4.07500500000000 , 1.69550000000000 )-- ( 4.07000500000000 , 1.69950000000000 )-- ( 4.06500500000000 , 1.66900000000000 )-- ( 4.06000500000000 , 1.70350000000000 )-- ( 4.05500500000000 , 1.70950000000000 )-- ( 4.05000500000000 , 1.65400000000000 )-- ( 4.04500500000000 , 1.67650000000000 )-- ( 4.04000500000000 , 1.73500000000000 )-- ( 4.03500500000000 , 1.71350000000000 )-- ( 4.03000500000000 , 1.66450000000000 )-- ( 4.02500500000000 , 1.71600000000000 )-- ( 4.02000500000000 , 1.68100000000000 )-- ( 4.01500500000000 , 1.66450000000000 )-- ( 4.01000500000000 , 1.69900000000000 )-- ( 4.00500500000000 , 1.69000000000000 )-- ( 4.00000500000000 , 1.66600000000000 )-- ( 3.99500500000000 , 1.67500000000000 )-- ( 3.99000500000000 , 1.70400000000000 )-- ( 3.98500500000000 , 1.71100000000000 )-- ( 3.98000500000000 , 1.70500000000000 )-- ( 3.97500500000000 , 1.71700000000000 )-- ( 3.97000500000000 , 1.66900000000000 )-- ( 3.96500500000000 , 1.72300000000000 )-- ( 3.96000500000000 , 1.84250000000000 )-- ( 3.95500500000000 , 1.84350000000000 )-- ( 3.95000500000000 , 1.82900000000000 )-- ( 3.94500500000000 , 1.88750000000000 )-- ( 3.94000500000000 , 1.84250000000000 )-- ( 3.93500500000000 , 1.80050000000000 )-- ( 3.93000500000000 , 1.85050000000000 )-- ( 3.92500500000000 , 1.87100000000000 )-- ( 3.92000500000000 , 1.86450000000000 )-- ( 3.91500500000000 , 1.85950000000000 )-- ( 3.91000500000000 , 1.89000000000000 )-- ( 3.90501000000000 , 1.90750000000000 )-- ( 3.90001000000000 , 1.83050000000000 )-- ( 3.89501000000000 , 1.84150000000000 )-- ( 3.89001000000000 , 1.84900000000000 )-- ( 3.88501000000000 , 1.85250000000000 )-- ( 3.88001000000000 , 1.87300000000000 )-- ( 3.87501000000000 , 1.85350000000000 )-- ( 3.87001000000000 , 1.85600000000000 )-- ( 3.86501000000000 , 1.88900000000000 )-- ( 3.86001000000000 , 1.90650000000000 )-- ( 3.85501000000000 , 1.88250000000000 )-- ( 3.85001000000000 , 1.86750000000000 )-- ( 3.84501000000000 , 1.87650000000000 )-- ( 3.84001000000000 , 1.84050000000000 )-- ( 3.83501000000000 , 1.87700000000000 )-- ( 3.83001000000000 , 1.92550000000000 )-- ( 3.82501000000000 , 1.92900000000000 )-- ( 3.82001000000000 , 1.92500000000000 )-- ( 3.81501000000000 , 1.89550000000000 )-- ( 3.81001000000000 , 1.94600000000000 )-- ( 3.80501000000000 , 1.92600000000000 )-- ( 3.80001000000000 , 1.94050000000000 )-- ( 3.79501000000000 , 1.85650000000000 )-- ( 3.79001000000000 , 1.94700000000000 )-- ( 3.78501000000000 , 1.93800000000000 )-- ( 3.78001000000000 , 1.87300000000000 )-- ( 3.77501000000000 , 1.88250000000000 )-- ( 3.77001000000000 , 1.91150000000000 )-- ( 3.76501000000000 , 1.91950000000000 )-- ( 3.76001000000000 , 1.91550000000000 )-- ( 3.75501000000000 , 1.93800000000000 )-- ( 3.75001000000000 , 1.99000000000000 )-- ( 3.74501000000000 , 1.91850000000000 )-- ( 3.74001000000000 , 1.90500000000000 )-- ( 3.73501000000000 , 1.97700000000000 )-- ( 3.73001000000000 , 1.95400000000000 )-- ( 3.72501000000000 , 1.94250000000000 )-- ( 3.72001000000000 , 1.95600000000000 )-- ( 3.71501000000000 , 1.90550000000000 )-- ( 3.71001000000000 , 1.98200000000000 )-- ( 3.70501000000000 , 1.94800000000000 )-- ( 3.70001000000000 , 1.92700000000000 )-- ( 3.69501000000000 , 1.92100000000000 )-- ( 3.69001000000000 , 2.58800000000000 )-- ( 3.68501000000000 , 2.57300000000000 )-- ( 3.68001000000000 , 2.56450000000000 )-- ( 3.67501000000000 , 2.60250000000000 )-- ( 3.67001000000000 , 2.60200000000000 )-- ( 3.66501000000000 , 2.58350000000000 )-- ( 3.66001000000000 , 2.60150000000000 )-- ( 3.65501000000000 , 2.59150000000000 )-- ( 3.65001000000000 , 2.58700000000000 )-- ( 3.64501000000000 , 2.61050000000000 )-- ( 3.64001000000000 , 2.59750000000000 )-- ( 3.63501000000000 , 2.61850000000000 )-- ( 3.63001000000000 , 2.63050000000000 )-- ( 3.62501000000000 , 2.57250000000000 )-- ( 3.62001000000000 , 2.60950000000000 )-- ( 3.61501000000000 , 2.61750000000000 )-- ( 3.61001000000000 , 2.61400000000000 )-- ( 3.60501000000000 , 2.63800000000000 )-- ( 3.60001000000000 , 2.62300000000000 )-- ( 3.59501000000000 , 2.64900000000000 )-- ( 3.59001000000000 , 2.63550000000000 )-- ( 3.58501000000000 , 2.62050000000000 )-- ( 3.58001000000000 , 2.65850000000000 )-- ( 3.57501000000000 , 2.63450000000000 )-- ( 3.57001000000000 , 2.62850000000000 )-- ( 3.56501000000000 , 2.59550000000000 )-- ( 3.56001000000000 , 2.63850000000000 )-- ( 3.55501000000000 , 2.59550000000000 )-- ( 3.55001000000000 , 2.65650000000000 )-- ( 3.54501000000000 , 2.64850000000000 )-- ( 3.54001000000000 , 2.64100000000000 )-- ( 3.53501000000000 , 2.64300000000000 )-- ( 3.53001000000000 , 2.64950000000000 )-- ( 3.52501000000000 , 2.65150000000000 )-- ( 3.52001000000000 , 2.65050000000000 )-- ( 3.51501500000000 , 2.62000000000000 )-- ( 3.51001500000000 , 2.65750000000000 )-- ( 3.50501500000000 , 2.64050000000000 )-- ( 3.50001500000000 , 2.65350000000000 )-- ( 3.49501500000000 , 2.65850000000000 )-- ( 3.49001500000000 , 2.70600000000000 )-- ( 3.48501500000000 , 2.65000000000000 )-- ( 3.48001500000000 , 2.69800000000000 )-- ( 3.47501500000000 , 2.63750000000000 )-- ( 3.47001500000000 , 2.71250000000000 )-- ( 3.46501500000000 , 2.63800000000000 )-- ( 3.46001500000000 , 2.65050000000000 )-- ( 3.45501500000000 , 2.69800000000000 )-- ( 3.45001500000000 , 2.67400000000000 )-- ( 3.44501500000000 , 2.64800000000000 )-- ( 3.44001500000000 , 2.68250000000000 )-- ( 3.43501500000000 , 2.65700000000000 )-- ( 3.43001500000000 , 2.71550000000000 )-- ( 3.42501500000000 , 2.71350000000000 )-- ( 3.42001500000000 , 2.71200000000000 )-- ( 3.41501500000000 , 2.69900000000000 )-- ( 3.41001500000000 , 2.62850000000000 )-- ( 3.40501500000000 , 2.68950000000000 )-- ( 3.40001500000000 , 2.73600000000000 )-- ( 3.39501500000000 , 2.71150000000000 )-- ( 3.39001500000000 , 2.67800000000000 )-- ( 3.38501500000000 , 2.67550000000000 )-- ( 3.38001500000000 , 2.73300000000000 )-- ( 3.37501500000000 , 2.73300000000000 )-- ( 3.37001500000000 , 2.64500000000000 )-- ( 3.36501500000000 , 2.71200000000000 )-- ( 3.36001500000000 , 2.69400000000000 )-- ( 3.35501500000000 , 2.66750000000000 )-- ( 3.35001500000000 , 2.72250000000000 )-- ( 3.34501500000000 , 2.77150000000000 )-- ( 3.34001500000000 , 2.69350000000000 )-- ( 3.33501500000000 , 2.69500000000000 )-- ( 3.33001500000000 , 2.66400000000000 )-- ( 3.32501500000000 , 2.71450000000000 )-- ( 3.32001500000000 , 2.70250000000000 )-- ( 3.31501500000000 , 2.69500000000000 )-- ( 3.31001500000000 , 2.70000000000000 )-- ( 3.30501500000000 , 2.74200000000000 )-- ( 3.30001500000000 , 2.70850000000000 )-- ( 3.29501500000000 , 2.71950000000000 )-- ( 3.29001500000000 , 2.68150000000000 )-- ( 3.28501500000000 , 2.69850000000000 )-- ( 3.28001500000000 , 2.80800000000000 )-- ( 3.27501500000000 , 2.73500000000000 )-- ( 3.27001500000000 , 2.77800000000000 )-- ( 3.26501500000000 , 2.83050000000000 )-- ( 3.26001500000000 , 2.76200000000000 )-- ( 3.25501500000000 , 2.76300000000000 )-- ( 3.25001500000000 , 2.77650000000000 )-- ( 3.24501500000000 , 2.75200000000000 )-- ( 3.24001500000000 , 2.78950000000000 )-- ( 3.23501500000000 , 2.76350000000000 )-- ( 3.23001500000000 , 2.90050000000000 )-- ( 3.22501500000000 , 2.89700000000000 )-- ( 3.22001500000000 , 2.87850000000000 )-- ( 3.21501500000000 , 2.92250000000000 )-- ( 3.21001500000000 , 2.89950000000000 )-- ( 3.20501500000000 , 2.92250000000000 )-- ( 3.20001500000000 , 2.93000000000000 )-- ( 3.19501500000000 , 2.89850000000000 )-- ( 3.19001500000000 , 2.86950000000000 )-- ( 3.18501500000000 , 2.91700000000000 )-- ( 3.18001500000000 , 2.89850000000000 )-- ( 3.17501500000000 , 2.88500000000000 )-- ( 3.17001500000000 , 2.88050000000000 )-- ( 3.16501500000000 , 2.89100000000000 )-- ( 3.16001500000000 , 2.83700000000000 )-- ( 3.15501500000000 , 2.91900000000000 )-- ( 3.15001500000000 , 2.90050000000000 )-- ( 3.14501500000000 , 2.94500000000000 )-- ( 3.14001500000000 , 2.94100000000000 )-- ( 3.13501500000000 , 2.92500000000000 )-- ( 3.13002000000000 , 2.88400000000000 )-- ( 3.12502000000000 , 2.89200000000000 )-- ( 3.12002000000000 , 2.89750000000000 )-- ( 3.11502000000000 , 2.87100000000000 )-- ( 3.11002000000000 , 2.94400000000000 )-- ( 3.10502000000000 , 2.91750000000000 )-- ( 3.10002000000000 , 2.93650000000000 )-- ( 3.09502000000000 , 2.94900000000000 )-- ( 3.09002000000000 , 2.94300000000000 )-- ( 3.08502000000000 , 2.97150000000000 )-- ( 3.08002000000000 , 2.98500000000000 )-- ( 3.07502000000000 , 2.96500000000000 )-- ( 3.07002000000000 , 2.99950000000000 )-- ( 3.06502000000000 , 2.93050000000000 )-- ( 3.06002000000000 , 2.94500000000000 )-- ( 3.05502000000000 , 2.97300000000000 )-- ( 3.05002000000000 , 2.95400000000000 )-- ( 3.04502000000000 , 2.96800000000000 )-- ( 3.04002000000000 , 2.95450000000000 )-- ( 3.03502000000000 , 3.02650000000000 )-- ( 3.03002000000000 , 3.01850000000000 )-- ( 3.02502000000000 , 2.94400000000000 )-- ( 3.02002000000000 , 2.98100000000000 )-- ( 3.01502000000000 , 2.97750000000000 )-- ( 3.01002000000000 , 3.04550000000000 )-- ( 3.00502000000000 , 3.06850000000000 )-- ( 3.00002000000000 , 3.07300000000000 )-- ( 2.99502000000000 , 3.02200000000000 )-- ( 2.99002000000000 , 2.99400000000000 )-- ( 2.98502000000000 , 3.04350000000000 )-- ( 2.98002000000000 , 3.05000000000000 )-- ( 2.97502000000000 , 3.06000000000000 )-- ( 2.97002000000000 , 3.02350000000000 )-- ( 2.96502000000000 , 3.03400000000000 )-- ( 2.96002000000000 , 3.03050000000000 )-- ( 2.95502000000000 , 3.04550000000000 )-- ( 2.95002000000000 , 3.06900000000000 )-- ( 2.94502000000000 , 3.03700000000000 )-- ( 2.94002000000000 , 3.08800000000000 )-- ( 2.93502000000000 , 3.08500000000000 )-- ( 2.93002000000000 , 3.03950000000000 )-- ( 2.92502000000000 , 3.21850000000000 )-- ( 2.92002000000000 , 3.23050000000000 )-- ( 2.91502000000000 , 3.19100000000000 )-- ( 2.91002000000000 , 3.22650000000000 )-- ( 2.90502000000000 , 3.19700000000000 )-- ( 2.90002000000000 , 3.18550000000000 )-- ( 2.89502000000000 , 3.19750000000000 )-- ( 2.89002000000000 , 3.20300000000000 )-- ( 2.88502000000000 , 3.22050000000000 )-- ( 2.88002000000000 , 3.15850000000000 )-- ( 2.87502000000000 , 3.19850000000000 )-- ( 2.87002000000000 , 3.17400000000000 )-- ( 2.86502000000000 , 3.22050000000000 )-- ( 2.86002000000000 , 3.20650000000000 )-- ( 2.85502000000000 , 3.19900000000000 )-- ( 2.85002000000000 , 3.19600000000000 )-- ( 2.84502000000000 , 3.24550000000000 )-- ( 2.84002000000000 , 3.21300000000000 )-- ( 2.83502000000000 , 3.15600000000000 )-- ( 2.83002000000000 , 3.17600000000000 )-- ( 2.82502000000000 , 3.21000000000000 )-- ( 2.82002000000000 , 3.21050000000000 )-- ( 2.81502000000000 , 3.20650000000000 )-- ( 2.81002000000000 , 3.21800000000000 )-- ( 2.80502000000000 , 3.22050000000000 )-- ( 2.80002000000000 , 3.20650000000000 )-- ( 2.79502000000000 , 3.14900000000000 )-- ( 2.79002000000000 , 3.17950000000000 )-- ( 2.78502000000000 , 3.19600000000000 )-- ( 2.78002000000000 , 3.19300000000000 )-- ( 2.77502000000000 , 3.21600000000000 )-- ( 2.77002000000000 , 3.23900000000000 )-- ( 2.76502000000000 , 3.43500000000000 )-- ( 2.76002000000000 , 3.41150000000000 )-- ( 2.75502000000000 , 3.42800000000000 )-- ( 2.75002000000000 , 3.39400000000000 )-- ( 2.74502000000000 , 3.36500000000000 )-- ( 2.74002500000000 , 3.36950000000000 )-- ( 2.73502500000000 , 3.38800000000000 )-- ( 2.73002500000000 , 3.37400000000000 )-- ( 2.72502500000000 , 3.45500000000000 )-- ( 2.72002500000000 , 3.40200000000000 )-- ( 2.71502500000000 , 3.39100000000000 )-- ( 2.71002500000000 , 3.37450000000000 )-- ( 2.70502500000000 , 3.40550000000000 )-- ( 2.70002500000000 , 3.37800000000000 )-- ( 2.69502500000000 , 3.45750000000000 )-- ( 2.69002500000000 , 3.40200000000000 )-- ( 2.68502500000000 , 3.39800000000000 )-- ( 2.68002500000000 , 3.36100000000000 )-- ( 2.67502500000000 , 3.41950000000000 )-- ( 2.67002500000000 , 3.42700000000000 )-- ( 2.66502500000000 , 3.39150000000000 )-- ( 2.66002500000000 , 3.38550000000000 )-- ( 2.65502500000000 , 3.42550000000000 )-- ( 2.65002500000000 , 3.40750000000000 )-- ( 2.64502500000000 , 3.39100000000000 )-- ( 2.64002500000000 , 3.43750000000000 )-- ( 2.63502500000000 , 3.41300000000000 )-- ( 2.63002500000000 , 3.39100000000000 )-- ( 2.62502500000000 , 3.43900000000000 )-- ( 2.62002500000000 , 3.40400000000000 )-- ( 2.61502500000000 , 3.37150000000000 )-- ( 2.61002500000000 , 3.38700000000000 )-- ( 2.60502500000000 , 3.41700000000000 )-- ( 2.60002500000000 , 3.37400000000000 )-- ( 2.59502500000000 , 3.43250000000000 )-- ( 2.59002500000000 , 3.43100000000000 )-- ( 2.58502500000000 , 3.43650000000000 )-- ( 2.58002500000000 , 3.43450000000000 )-- ( 2.57502500000000 , 3.44900000000000 )-- ( 2.57002500000000 , 3.41150000000000 )-- ( 2.56502500000000 , 3.44900000000000 )-- ( 2.56002500000000 , 3.40100000000000 )-- ( 2.55502500000000 , 3.45500000000000 )-- ( 2.55002500000000 , 3.42600000000000 )-- ( 2.54502500000000 , 3.42700000000000 )-- ( 2.54002500000000 , 3.46750000000000 )-- ( 2.53502500000000 , 3.45850000000000 )-- ( 2.53002500000000 , 3.44300000000000 )-- ( 2.52502500000000 , 3.48050000000000 )-- ( 2.52002500000000 , 3.48150000000000 )-- ( 2.51502500000000 , 3.49750000000000 )-- ( 2.51002500000000 , 3.51150000000000 )-- ( 2.50502500000000 , 3.48200000000000 )-- ( 2.50002500000000 , 3.49900000000000 );
\draw ( 2.9502500000000 , 2.36950000000000 ) node{$p_2=0.3 $};


\draw (0,0) -- (5.0,0);
\draw (0,0)-- (0,5);
\draw (0,-0.5) node{$O$};
\draw (5*0.2,-0.2) node{0.2};
\draw (5*0.2,-0.1)--(5*0.2,0.1);
\draw (5*0.4,-0.2) node{0.4};
\draw (5*0.4,-0.1)--(5*0.4,0.1);
\draw (5*0.6,-0.2) node{0.6};
\draw (5*0.6,-0.1)--(5*0.6,0.1);
\draw (5*0.8,-0.2) node{0.8};
\draw (5*0.8,-0.1)--(5*0.8,0.1);

\draw (-0.4,5*0.2) node{0.2};
\draw (-0.1,5*0.2)--(0.1,5*0.2);
\draw (-0.4,5*0.4) node{0.4};
\draw (-0.1,5*0.4)--(0.1,5*0.4);
\draw (-0.4,5*0.6) node{0.6};
\draw (-0.1,5*0.6)--(0.1,5*0.6);
\draw (-0.4,5*0.8) node{0.8};
\draw (-0.1,5*0.8)--(0.1,5*0.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{.}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htp]
%\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw [color=black, fill=gray!50] (8*0.375,8*0.25) -- (8*0.6666,4*0.33333) -- (8*0.33333,8*0.33333) -- (1,4) -- cycle;

\draw ( 4.5 , 1.9405 )-- ( 4.495 , 1.92 )-- ( 4.49 , 1.9235 )-- ( 4.485 , 1.9855 )-- ( 4.48 , 1.9285 )-- ( 4.475 , 1.979 )-- ( 4.47 , 1.933 )-- ( 4.465 , 1.961 )-- ( 4.46 , 1.9645 )-- ( 4.455 , 1.96 )-- ( 4.45 , 1.9535 )-- ( 4.445 , 1.953 )-- ( 4.44 , 1.9215 )-- ( 4.435 , 1.9585 )-- ( 4.43 , 1.9275 )-- ( 4.425 , 1.978 )-- ( 4.42 , 1.959 )-- ( 4.415 , 2.029 )-- ( 4.41 , 1.9925 )-- ( 4.405 , 2.0005 )-- ( 4.4 , 2.0395 )-- ( 4.395 , 2.0265 )-- ( 4.39 , 1.9645 )-- ( 4.385 , 2.026 )-- ( 4.38 , 2.0355 )-- ( 4.375 , 2.023 )-- ( 4.37 , 2.021 )-- ( 4.365 , 1.9905 )-- ( 4.36 , 1.99 )-- ( 4.355 , 1.984 )-- ( 4.35 , 1.9575 )-- ( 4.345 , 1.9865 )-- ( 4.34 , 2.03 )-- ( 4.335 , 2.071 )-- ( 4.33 , 2.0245 )-- ( 4.325 , 2.0265 )-- ( 4.32 , 1.9655 )-- ( 4.315 , 2.105 )-- ( 4.31 , 2.0805 )-- ( 4.305 , 2.1025 )-- ( 4.3 , 2.1135 )-- ( 4.295 , 2.08 )-- ( 4.29 , 2.1045 )-- ( 4.285 , 2.1015 )-- ( 4.28 , 2.088 )-- ( 4.275 , 2.0535 )-- ( 4.27 , 2.093 )-- ( 4.265 , 2.047 )-- ( 4.26 , 2.053 )-- ( 4.255 , 2.0975 )-- ( 4.25 , 2.073 )-- ( 4.245 , 2.123 )-- ( 4.24 , 2.1185 )-- ( 4.235 , 2.07 )-- ( 4.23 , 2.059 )-- ( 4.225 , 2.1055 )-- ( 4.22 , 2.0875 )-- ( 4.215 , 2.1105 )-- ( 4.21 , 2.0805 )-- ( 4.205 , 2.1545 )-- ( 4.2 , 2.125 )-- ( 4.195 , 2.1045 )-- ( 4.19 , 2.101 )-- ( 4.185 , 2.1215 )-- ( 4.18 , 2.151 )-- ( 4.175 , 2.1285 )-- ( 4.17 , 2.1255 )-- ( 4.165 , 2.0715 )-- ( 4.16 , 2.076 )-- ( 4.155 , 2.1225 )-- ( 4.15 , 2.1325 )-- ( 4.145 , 2.104 )-- ( 4.14 , 2.1285 )-- ( 4.135 , 2.082 )-- ( 4.13 , 2.1145 )-- ( 4.125 , 2.0945 )-- ( 4.12 , 2.085 )-- ( 4.115 , 2.099 )-- ( 4.11 , 2.1085 )-- ( 4.105 , 2.14 )-- ( 4.1 , 2.355 )-- ( 4.095 , 2.318 )-- ( 4.09 , 2.3745 )-- ( 4.085 , 2.298 )-- ( 4.08 , 2.3125 )-- ( 4.075 , 2.3675 )-- ( 4.07 , 2.326 )-- ( 4.065 , 2.3515 )-- ( 4.06 , 2.3205 )-- ( 4.055 , 2.336 )-- ( 4.05 , 2.3655 )-- ( 4.045 , 2.3265 )-- ( 4.04 , 2.3075 )-- ( 4.035 , 2.3515 )-- ( 4.03 , 2.297 )-- ( 4.025 , 2.278 )-- ( 4.02 , 2.353 )-- ( 4.015 , 2.351 )-- ( 4.01 , 2.282 )-- ( 4.005 , 2.313 )-- ( 4.0 , 2.3695 )-- ( 3.995 , 2.381 )-- ( 3.99 , 2.3635 )-- ( 3.985 , 2.356 )-- ( 3.98 , 2.374 )-- ( 3.975 , 2.3365 )-- ( 3.97 , 2.326 )-- ( 3.965 , 2.3405 )-- ( 3.96 , 2.3425 )-- ( 3.955 , 2.367 )-- ( 3.95 , 2.341 )-- ( 3.945 , 2.3525 )-- ( 3.94 , 2.3375 )-- ( 3.935 , 2.3775 )-- ( 3.93 , 2.364 )-- ( 3.925 , 2.3915 )-- ( 3.92 , 2.521 )-- ( 3.915 , 2.588 )-- ( 3.91 , 2.5915 )-- ( 3.905 , 2.5695 )-- ( 3.9 , 2.547 )-- ( 3.895 , 2.571 )-- ( 3.89 , 2.59 )-- ( 3.885 , 2.5675 )-- ( 3.88 , 2.577 )-- ( 3.875 , 2.556 )-- ( 3.87 , 2.5645 )-- ( 3.865 , 2.5665 )-- ( 3.86 , 2.6245 )-- ( 3.855 , 2.56 )-- ( 3.85 , 2.5955 )-- ( 3.845 , 2.626 )-- ( 3.84 , 2.601 )-- ( 3.835 , 2.593 )-- ( 3.83 , 2.6225 )-- ( 3.825 , 2.59 )-- ( 3.82 , 2.618 )-- ( 3.815 , 2.6215 )-- ( 3.81 , 2.6495 )-- ( 3.805 , 2.628 )-- ( 3.8 , 2.658 )-- ( 3.795 , 2.6335 )-- ( 3.79 , 2.616 )-- ( 3.785 , 2.646 )-- ( 3.78 , 2.6155 )-- ( 3.775 , 2.6175 )-- ( 3.77 , 2.663 )-- ( 3.765 , 2.609 )-- ( 3.76 , 2.6795 )-- ( 3.755 , 2.6405 )-- ( 3.75 , 2.6185 )-- ( 3.745 , 2.6365 )-- ( 3.74 , 2.6365 )-- ( 3.735 , 2.607 )-- ( 3.73 , 2.6125 )-- ( 3.725 , 2.627 )-- ( 3.72 , 2.645 )-- ( 3.715 , 2.6475 )-- ( 3.71 , 2.6735 )-- ( 3.705 , 2.681 )-- ( 3.7 , 2.6585 )-- ( 3.695 , 2.6715 )-- ( 3.69 , 2.6915 )-- ( 3.685 , 2.643 )-- ( 3.68 , 2.643 )-- ( 3.675 , 2.6695 )-- ( 3.67 , 2.646 )-- ( 3.665 , 2.651 )-- ( 3.66 , 2.665 )-- ( 3.655 , 2.64 )-- ( 3.65 , 2.6605 )-- ( 3.645 , 2.663 )-- ( 3.64 , 2.6205 )-- ( 3.635 , 2.6585 )-- ( 3.63 , 3.2845 )-- ( 3.625 , 3.243 )-- ( 3.62 , 3.269 )-- ( 3.615 , 3.291 )-- ( 3.61 , 3.2675 )-- ( 3.605 , 3.283 )-- ( 3.6 , 3.226 )-- ( 3.595 , 3.2885 )-- ( 3.59 , 3.2805 )-- ( 3.585 , 3.2245 )-- ( 3.58 , 3.203 )-- ( 3.575 , 3.197 )-- ( 3.57 , 3.2615 )-- ( 3.565 , 3.2145 )-- ( 3.56 , 3.28 )-- ( 3.555 , 3.279 )-- ( 3.55 , 3.3245 )-- ( 3.545 , 3.29 )-- ( 3.54 , 3.282 )-- ( 3.535 , 3.277 )-- ( 3.53 , 3.2595 )-- ( 3.525 , 3.2735 )-- ( 3.52 , 3.3035 )-- ( 3.515 , 3.2885 )-- ( 3.51 , 3.291 )-- ( 3.505 , 3.3035 )-- ( 3.5 , 3.2835 )-- ( 3.495 , 3.2795 )-- ( 3.49 , 3.339 )-- ( 3.485 , 3.277 )-- ( 3.48 , 3.3235 )-- ( 3.475 , 3.277 )-- ( 3.47 , 3.368 )-- ( 3.465 , 3.303 )-- ( 3.46 , 3.3415 )-- ( 3.455 , 3.3255 )-- ( 3.45 , 3.3695 )-- ( 3.445 , 3.31 )-- ( 3.44 , 3.3415 )-- ( 3.435 , 3.3555 )-- ( 3.43 , 3.3495 )-- ( 3.425 , 3.356 )-- ( 3.42 , 3.3725 )-- ( 3.415 , 3.3845 )-- ( 3.41 , 3.3775 )-- ( 3.405 , 3.374 )-- ( 3.4 , 3.3415 )-- ( 3.395 , 3.349 )-- ( 3.39 , 3.349 )-- ( 3.385 , 3.3235 )-- ( 3.38 , 3.343 )-- ( 3.375 , 3.3945 )-- ( 3.37 , 3.3595 )-- ( 3.365 , 3.383 )-- ( 3.36 , 3.318 )-- ( 3.355 , 3.3465 )-- ( 3.35 , 3.373 )-- ( 3.345 , 3.3435 )-- ( 3.34 , 3.388 )-- ( 3.335 , 3.331 )-- ( 3.33 , 3.3625 )-- ( 3.325 , 3.3795 )-- ( 3.32 , 3.395 )-- ( 3.315 , 3.3675 )-- ( 3.31 , 3.3485 )-- ( 3.305 , 3.333 )-- ( 3.3 , 3.308 )-- ( 3.295 , 3.3515 )-- ( 3.29 , 3.343 )-- ( 3.285 , 3.358 )-- ( 3.28 , 3.3575 )-- ( 3.275 , 3.354 )-- ( 3.27 , 3.361 )-- ( 3.265 , 3.3585 )-- ( 3.26 , 3.376 )-- ( 3.255 , 3.359 )-- ( 3.25 , 3.3355 )-- ( 3.245 , 3.353 )-- ( 3.24 , 3.3675 )-- ( 3.235 , 3.3745 )-- ( 3.23 , 3.3635 )-- ( 3.225 , 3.358 )-- ( 3.22 , 3.4215 )-- ( 3.215 , 3.3895 )-- ( 3.21 , 3.3995 )-- ( 3.205 , 3.408 )-- ( 3.2 , 3.3655 )-- ( 3.195 , 3.387 )-- ( 3.19 , 3.3775 )-- ( 3.185 , 3.4095 )-- ( 3.18 , 3.3915 )-- ( 3.175 , 3.355 )-- ( 3.17 , 3.385 )-- ( 3.165 , 3.382 )-- ( 3.16 , 3.3945 )-- ( 3.155 , 3.372 )-- ( 3.15 , 3.4195 )-- ( 3.145 , 3.394 )-- ( 3.14 , 3.3915 )-- ( 3.135 , 3.4 )-- ( 3.13 , 3.461 )-- ( 3.125 , 3.463 )-- ( 3.12 , 3.46 )-- ( 3.115 , 3.452 )-- ( 3.11 , 3.5575 )-- ( 3.105 , 3.5495 )-- ( 3.1 , 3.562 )-- ( 3.095 , 3.531 )-- ( 3.09 , 3.5615 )-- ( 3.085 , 3.5105 )-- ( 3.08 , 3.54 )-- ( 3.075 , 3.5245 )-- ( 3.07 , 3.539 )-- ( 3.065 , 3.551 )-- ( 3.06 , 3.572 )-- ( 3.055 , 3.5345 )-- ( 3.05 , 3.6125 )-- ( 3.045 , 3.6425 )-- ( 3.04 , 3.6155 )-- ( 3.035 , 3.623 )-- ( 3.03 , 3.646 )-- ( 3.025 , 3.602 )-- ( 3.02 , 3.621 )-- ( 3.015 , 3.588 )-- ( 3.01 , 3.6005 )-- ( 3.005 , 3.6225 )-- ( 3.0 , 3.6175 )-- ( 2.995 , 3.6265 )-- ( 2.99 , 3.6195 )-- ( 2.985 , 3.6185 )-- ( 2.98 , 3.6105 )-- ( 2.975 , 3.669 )-- ( 2.97 , 3.594 )-- ( 2.965 , 3.633 )-- ( 2.96 , 3.6335 )-- ( 2.955 , 3.658 )-- ( 2.95 , 3.6425 )-- ( 2.945 , 3.6375 )-- ( 2.94 , 3.6005 )-- ( 2.935 , 3.644 )-- ( 2.93 , 3.6315 )-- ( 2.925 , 3.659 )-- ( 2.92 , 3.684 )-- ( 2.915 , 3.6435 )-- ( 2.91 , 3.683 )-- ( 2.905 , 3.679 )-- ( 2.9 , 3.686 )-- ( 2.895 , 3.6665 )-- ( 2.89 , 3.685 )-- ( 2.885 , 3.6335 )-- ( 2.88 , 3.669 )-- ( 2.875 , 3.663 )-- ( 2.87 , 3.6545 )-- ( 2.865 , 3.6415 )-- ( 2.86 , 3.684 )-- ( 2.855 , 3.6495 )-- ( 2.85 , 3.686 )-- ( 2.845 , 3.797 )-- ( 2.84 , 3.78 )-- ( 2.835 , 3.792 )-- ( 2.83 , 3.8145 )-- ( 2.825 , 3.7675 )-- ( 2.82 , 3.7835 )-- ( 2.815 , 3.823 )-- ( 2.81 , 3.7785 )-- ( 2.805 , 3.8055 )-- ( 2.8 , 3.794 )-- ( 2.795 , 3.7985 )-- ( 2.79 , 3.8 )-- ( 2.785 , 3.7795 )-- ( 2.78 , 3.7785 )-- ( 2.775 , 3.8035 )-- ( 2.77 , 3.747 )-- ( 2.765 , 3.824 )-- ( 2.76 , 3.831 )-- ( 2.755 , 3.792 )-- ( 2.75 , 3.8255 )-- ( 2.745 , 3.837 )-- ( 2.74 , 3.81 )-- ( 2.735 , 3.798 )-- ( 2.73 , 3.8225 )-- ( 2.725 , 3.7585 )-- ( 2.72 , 3.769 )-- ( 2.715 , 3.7905 )-- ( 2.71 , 3.8045 )-- ( 2.705 , 3.844 )-- ( 2.7 , 3.829 )-- ( 2.695 , 3.8225 )-- ( 2.69 , 3.834 )-- ( 2.685 , 3.8185 )-- ( 2.68 , 3.8425 )-- ( 2.675 , 3.796 )-- ( 2.67 , 3.8075 )-- ( 2.665 , 3.825 )-- ( 2.66 , 3.7855 )-- ( 2.655 , 3.816 )-- ( 2.65 , 3.8295 )-- ( 2.645 , 3.7945 )-- ( 2.64 , 3.8275 )-- ( 2.635 , 3.8235 )-- ( 2.63 , 3.805 )-- ( 2.625 , 3.8125 )-- ( 2.62 , 3.8035 )-- ( 2.615 , 3.8175 )-- ( 2.61 , 3.877 )-- ( 2.605 , 3.8435 )-- ( 2.6 , 3.8225 )-- ( 2.595 , 3.8395 )-- ( 2.59 , 3.8455 )-- ( 2.585 , 3.8585 )-- ( 2.58 , 3.8355 )-- ( 2.575 , 3.826 )-- ( 2.57 , 3.805 )-- ( 2.565 , 3.8395 )-- ( 2.56 , 3.838 )-- ( 2.555 , 3.945 )-- ( 2.55 , 3.96 )-- ( 2.545 , 3.9585 )-- ( 2.54 , 3.9565 )-- ( 2.535 , 3.9595 )-- ( 2.53 , 3.978 )-- ( 2.525 , 3.9495 )-- ( 2.52 , 3.9815 )-- ( 2.515 , 3.983 )-- ( 2.51 , 3.964 )-- ( 2.505 , 3.968 )-- ( 2.5 , 3.991 ) node{$p_2=0.4$};


\draw (0,0) -- (5.0,0);
\draw (0,0)-- (0,5);
\draw (0,-0.5) node{$O$};
\draw (5*0.2,-0.2) node{0.2};
\draw (5*0.2,-0.1)--(5*0.2,0.1);
\draw (5*0.4,-0.2) node{0.4};
\draw (5*0.4,-0.1)--(5*0.4,0.1);
\draw (5*0.6,-0.2) node{0.6};
\draw (5*0.6,-0.1)--(5*0.6,0.1);
\draw (5*0.8,-0.2) node{0.8};
\draw (5*0.8,-0.1)--(5*0.8,0.1);

\draw (-0.4,5*0.2) node{0.2};
\draw (-0.1,5*0.2)--(0.1,5*0.2);
\draw (-0.4,5*0.4) node{0.4};
\draw (-0.1,5*0.4)--(0.1,5*0.4);
\draw (-0.4,5*0.6) node{0.6};
\draw (-0.1,5*0.6)--(0.1,5*0.6);
\draw (-0.4,5*0.8) node{0.8};
\draw (-0.1,5*0.8)--(0.1,5*0.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{.}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- For placing one picture beside the other, use one figure environment for both.
- For captions and labels for each one of those pictures, you could use the [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package or the [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package.
- For making the pictures smaller, you could use `\resizebox` or `scalebox` of the [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package, or TikZ options, such as `[scale=<factor>,transform shape]`.

```
\usepackage{subfig}
...
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \subfloat[caption]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,transform shape]
    \draw ...
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \label{fig1}}
  \subfloat[caption]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,transform shape]
    \draw ...
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \label{fig2}}
\end{figure}
```

[image: graphs next to each other]

Answer (score 4):

If you could export your coordinate pairs as data sets to files, you could easily use the [pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) package to get nice plots. For alignment as sub-figures you can alternatively use the [subcaption](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package that is shipped with [caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[!ht]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
          \addplot[black] file {data-1.csv};
          \addlegendentry{$p_2=0.3$};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{First sub-figure}\label{subfig-1:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
          \addplot[black] file {data-2.csv};
          \addlegendentry{$p_2=0.4$};
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{Second sub-figure}\label{subfig-2:dummy}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Dummy figure}\label{fig-dummy}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to attach the data sets here.

---

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is a minimum working example.

Comment: @JG: You must have very high expectations regarding a minimal example. Perhaps you can elaborate. But you are free to provide a better answer (instead of just voting my answer down).

Comment: @ThorstenDonig You are so funny!  I meant that I think it was more like a maximum working example.  Who voted you down?  How do you know who votes who what?